# Resolving a async variable already in the routeprovider

Tags: angularjs

I have two async functions and i need to resolve one of them already in the resolve section of the routeProvider. When a User types an object on the url i want to automatically add a startdate and a enddate. My Problem is that the dates are resolved to late. Because if i do a console.log(datetable) in my Controller, it shows that `dobject` is resolved correctly. But this is to late, i also need the dates when i call ObjectService.get(), because right now it just searches for /object(which produces an 404) and not for /object/startdate/enddate because the variables are null. How can i resolve the dates before i call ObjectService.get()?

My Factory and Service Methods

```
.factory("ObjectService", ["$resource", function($resource) {
                return $resource('/:object/:startdate/:enddate');
            }])
            .service("CurrentDates", ["DateService", function(DateService) {
                this.dates = function() {

                    DateService.query().$promise.then(function(info) {
                        currentdates.startdate = info.start;
                        currentdates.enddate = info.end;
                    }).catch(onError);
                    return currentdates;
                }
            }])

            .factory("DateService", ["$resource", function($resource) {
                return $resource('dates.json');
            }])
```

My Routeprovider

```
$routeProvider
            .when('/:object', {
                templateUrl: "template/table.html",
                controller: 'ObjectController',
                resolve: {
                    datetable: ["ObjectService", "CurrentDates", "$route",
                        function(ObjectService, CurrentDates, $route) {
                            var dates = CurrentDates.dates(); // dates should already be resolved here if possible
                            return ObjectService.get(Object.assign($route.current.params, dates)).$promise
                                .catch(function(errorResponse) {
                                    return {
                                        "error": errorResponse.status,
                                        "object": $route.current.params.object,
                                        "dobject": Object.assign($route.current.params, dates)
                                    };
                                });
                        }
                    ],
                }
            })
```

I tried to write it like this but it didnt work.

```
return CurrentDates.dates().then(function(dates) {
    return ObjectService.get(Object.assign($route.current.params, dates))
        .$promise.catch(function(errorResponse) {
            return {
                "error": errorResponse.status,
                "object": $route.current.params.object,
                "dobject": Object.assign($route.current.params, dates)
            };
        });
})
```

Comment: `CurrentDates` doesn't appear to have a `current()` function.  That *might* be a typo, and you might be meaning `CurrentDates.dates()`.  However, that function isn't returning a promise, it is returning an object that is empty, because `DateService.query`is the async portion.  `resolve` needs to receive the promise object, which means the `.then` in your service either needs to be wrapped, or you need to do that `.then` logic somewhere else.

Comment: You got me there, fixed the mistake. About the 'then', i thought the problem was something like that. I'm just not sure how to do it exactly, but ty your answer helps me to understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it thanks to Claies hints. I had to rewrite my service method to:

```
.service("CurrentDates", ["DateService", function(DateService) {
            var currentdates = {
                startdate: null,
                enddate: null
            };
                this.dates = function() {
                    return  DateService.query().$promise.then(function(info) {
                        currentdates.startdate = info.start;
                        currentdates.enddate = info.end;
                        return currentdates;
                    }).catch(onError);
                }
            }])
```

Then i could resolve the variable datatable in the routeProvider:

```
datetable:     ["ObjectService", "CurrentDates", "$route",
            function(ObjectService, CurrentDates, $route) {
                return CurrentDates.dates().then(function(dates) {
                    return ObjectService.get(Object.assign($route.current.params, dates))
                        .$promise.catch(function(errorResponse) {
                            return {
                                "error": errorResponse.status,
                                "object": $route.current.params.object,
                                "dobject": Object.assign($route.current.params, dates)
                            };
                        });
                })
            ]
```